# Passing Generic Object to Method

Tags: c#, generics

I want to pass generic(can be of any type) model/class to a method. How to pass that?

```
if(NewUser)
    MethodA(User);
else
    MethodA(UserReg);
```

Let me add some more code :

```
private void SetRegionDummy<T>(T obj)
{
    foreach (var lookup in obj)
    { 
        // but obj.(obj dot) does not give properties of PcvCompleteViewModel
    }
}

//Call this method
SetRegionDummy(this.PcvCompleteViewModel);

[Serializable]
public class PcvCompleteViewModel : StepViewModelBase
{
    #region Constructor


    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public List<ChargeVolume> ChargeVolumes { get; set; }

    public List<LookUpViewModel> LookUp { get; set; }
    public List<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
    public List<ProductViewModel> PricingProducts { get; set; }
    public List<RegionViewModel> Regions { get; set; }
    public decimal ContractYears { get; set; }      
    public decimal? PropGrowthRate { get; set; }
    public decimal? GnicsGrowthRate { get; set; }
}
```

The method is the same but how to pass a different object model?

Comment: No need for generics here. You can use method overloading. Two methods with same name but different parameters.

Comment: I dont want to create two methods with same code.

Comment: Do `User` and `UserReg` share a common interface or base class?  If not, you won't really benefit from generics here.

Comment: When you say same code -- I guess you need an interface / base class.

Comment: In your updated example your try to apply a `foreach` on the the obj. what type of T are you expecteding. ie: what type is `lookup`. It looks like you are asking about type constraints on a generic type but you haven't provided enough information to make this clear.

Comment: PcvCompleteViewModel type

Comment: is `PcvCompleteViewModel` an `IEnumerable` of another type

Comment: PcvCompleteViewModel is class with properties

Comment: Please give us your real code, an not something that, in you opinion, resembles that. Show us `PcvCompleteViewModel` class and any other class you want to use inside your method.

Comment: [Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far. That way people can use it to reproduce the problem and give much better answers.

Comment: i have added PcvCompleteViewModel class above

Answer (score 2):

Both your classes must at least share an interface, or inherit from a common base class, that declares the property you want to be shared among them or else you will not be able to create a method that uses this property.

In your example, you do not need generics at all. Assuming your classes are declared this way:

```
public class ClassA : IMyInterface {
    public IEnumerable<LookUpViewModel> LookUp { get; set; }
    public int MyPropertyA { get; set; }
    //other properties
}

public class ClassB : IMyInterface {
    public IEnumerable<LookUpViewModel> LookUp { get; set; }
    public string MyPropertyB { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

With a common interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    IEnumerable<LookUpViewModel> LookUp { get; set; }
}
```

You can simply create a method that uses this interface as parameter:

```
private void SetRegionDummy(IMyInterface obj)
{
    foreach (var lookup in obj.LookUp)
    {
        DoWork(lookup);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T genericInput)
{
    //do stuff with input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to care about the object type, use Generics.

```
public void MethodA<T>(T obj) {
    // do stuff
}
```

If you don't, just change the parameter type to `object`.

```
public void MethodA(object obj) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics in **C#** can be defined by the calling method when the method signature that looks like the following ([details on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)):

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T viewModel) where T : IEnumerable<IViewModel>
{
}
```

Note, that you can use the `where` syntax to provide type constraints. Then you can invoke this like so:

```
{
    var viewModel = GetViewModel();
    MyMethod<PcvCompleteViewModel>(viewModel );
}
```